# Using Core NodeJs modules in Firefox addons

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox

I am trying out firefox add-on sdk, i am confused about one thing. When developing firefox extensions using JPM, Can we,

use 3rd party modules added with npm ?
use core nodejs modules ? (like 'net')

When i add 3rd party modules using npm, some modules can be loaded but some modules fails giving error message:

Message: Module `xxx` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/xxx.js

Some examples would be 'net'  and 'util' modules.

Is there a way to make firefox add-ons, core nodejs modules (like 'net') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently cannot use node modules like that directly in extensions for Firefox or any other browser.

For some things you might be able to get by with using something like `browserify`, but for node core modules like `net`, `fs`, `dgram`, and others that utilize low, OS-level functionality, it's not exactly possible to simply `browserify` them.

There have been various efforts at writing shims for browsers, such as [`node-chromify`](https://github.com/iceddev/node-chromify) for Chrome extensions, but that project seems to have been abandoned some time ago.

There's also the possibility of embedding *node itself* into the extension, but that would make it quite bulky and limited to a particular platform (although there are some Firefox extensions that seem to have done just this).